# Kendo UI not scrolling up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, kendo-ui

I am developing and app Using Telerik using Cordova and Kendo UI.
I am having the problem that if I scroll down in a div an then switched to div using a simple display:none on the current scrolled div and a display:block to the new div I want to see that the whole app stays scrolled down and I am having no option for scrolling up I have just got a empty screen.

Here the code I am using:

```
<body onload="onDeviceReady();logint();">
    <div id="tabstrip-home"
        data-role="view"
        data-title="Login"
        data-model="app.loginService.viewModel">

        <div id="startupForm" data-role="view" style="display:block;">
            <img id="startup" class="startup" src="styles/images/startup.jpg"/>
            <input id="closeStartButton" onclick="closeStart();" type="image" src="styles/images/vor.png" name="image" width="40" height="40" style="bottom:0;position:fixed;right:0;">
        </div>

        <div class="logo-image" id="top" name="top"></div>
        <div id="home" data-role="scroller" style="display:none;">
            <div id="homeOverview" style="background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);margin-left: 5px;margin-right: 5px;color:black;box-shadow: 3px 3px 20px black;">
                <h3 style="padding-top:5px;">Angemeldet als: <span id="user"></span></h3>
                <div id="statsNr" style="display:none;">
                    <h3 >Zählwerke gesamt: <span id="zaehler"></span></h3>
                    <h3 style="padding-bottom:5px;">Zählwerke erfasst: <span id="zaehlererfasst"></span></h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="auftragGeladenUndDa">
                <div style="margin-left:10px;">
                    <button data-role="button" data-bind="click: showTermine" style="height: 50px;width: 30%;  padding-top: 0.75em; text-align: center;">
                    Termine
                    </button>
                    <button data-role="button" data-bind="click: schhin" style="height: 50px;width: 30%;  padding-top: 0.75em; text-align: center;">
                    Schlüsselliste
                    </button>
                    <button data-role="button" data-bind="click: showStats" style="height: 50px;width: 30%; padding-top: 0.75em; text-align: center;">
                    Statistik
                    </button>
                    <button data-role="button" onclick="test();" data-bind="click: showAbles" style="height: 50px;width: 61%; padding-top: 0.75em; text-align: center;">
                    Erfassen
                    </button>
                    <button id="homeErfass" data-bind="click: showUpload"  data-role="button" style="height: 50px;width: 30%;  padding-top: 0.75em; text-align: center;">
                    Ergebnisse übermitteln
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="auftragNichtDa">
                <button id="auftrag" onclick="kAuftragLaden();" data-bind="click: geladen" data-role="button" style="width: 90%; margin: 1em; padding-top: 0.75em;padding-right: 1.5em;padding-bottom: 0.8125em;padding-left: 1.5em; text-align: center;">
                    Neuen Auftrag laden
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="hinweiseForm" style="display:none;">
            <h3 id="row" style="color:black;">Hinweis und Schlüsselliste</h3>
            <table id="hinweis" border="0" style="z-index: 1;background-color:white;margin-left: 10px;margin-right: 10px;margin-bottom:5%;">
                <tr>
                </tr>
         </table>
        </div>

        <div id="terminForm" data-role="view" style="display:none;">
            <h3 id="row" style="color:black;">Termine</h3>
            <div style="background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);margin-left: 5px;margin-right: 5px;color:black;box-shadow: 3px 3px 20px black;">
            <p>Keine Termine vorhanden</p>
                </div>
        </div>

        <div id="uploadForm" data-role="view" style="display:none;">
            <h3 id="row" style="color:black;">Ergebnisse übermitteln</h3>
            <div id="uploadEinheit" style="background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:3px;margin-bottom:3px;margin-left: 5px;margin-right: 5px;color:black;box-shadow: 3px 3px 20px black;">
            <input id="theCheckbox" type="checkbox">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="statsForm" style="display:none;" >
            <div style="background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);margin-left: 5px;margin-right: 5px;color:black;box-shadow: 3px 3px 20px black;">
                <h3 id="row" style="padding-top:5px;">Statistik</h3>
                <h3 >Zählwerke gesamt: <span id="zaehlerin"></span></h3>
                <h3 style="padding-bottom:5px;">Zählwerke erfasst: <span id="zaehlererfasstin"></span></h3>
            </div>
            <div style="background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);margin-left: 5px;margin-right: 5px;color:black;box-shadow: 3px 3px 20px black;padding-top: 10px;">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-style="inset" >
                <li><div style="color:black;">Ort:</div>
                    <label>
                        <select style="color:black;" onchange="onchangeOrt();" id="statOrt"></select>
                    </label>
                </li>

            </ul>
                <ul data-role="listview" data-style="inset" >
                <li>
                    <div style="color:black;">Strasse</div>
                    <label>
                        <select style="color:black;" onchange="onchangeStrasse();" id="statOrt"></select>
                    </label>
                </li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="savedStrasse"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="ablesForm" style="display:none;" >
             <ul data-role="listview" data-style="inset">
                 <h3 id="row" style="color:black;margin-bottom: 0;margin-top: 0;">Orte</h3>
                <li>

                    <input id="stift" type="image" src="styles/images/erfassen.png" name="image" width="40" height="40" style="">
                    <input type="image" src="styles/images/suchen.png" name="image" width="40" height="40" style="">
                    <input type="image" src="styles/images/foto.png" name="image" width="40" height="40" style="">
                    <input type="image" src="styles/images/karte.png" name="image" width="40" height="40" style="">
                </li>
                 <li>

                     <select id="recog" onchange="changeFunc();" style="color:black;left: 0;width: 200px;"> </select>
                     <select id="2tab" onchange="changeAnz2();" style="margin-right:60px;color:black"><option value="1">K</option><option value="2">Z</option></select>
                     <select id="alleOffen" onchange="changeAnz2();" style="color:black;"><option value="1">Alle</option><option value="2">Offen</option></select>
                 </li>
             </ul>
             <div id="all1" style="font-size: 18pt;height:95%;background-color:white;margin-top: 0;margin-left:25px;margin-right:25px;box-shadow: 3px 3px 20px black;"></div>
             <div id="all2" style="font-size: 18pt;height:95%;display:none;"></div>
             <div id="all3" style="font-size: 18pt;height:95%;display:none;"></div>
             <div id="all4" style="font-size: 18pt;height:95%;display:none;"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="erfassForm" style="display:none;" >
            <div style="background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);margin-left: 5px;margin-right: 5px;color:black;box-shadow: 3px 3px 20px black;padding-top: 1px;">
            <h3 style="color:black;display:none;" id="erfassName"></h3>
            <h3 style="color:black;" id="erfassNameAnz"></h3>
            <h3 style="color:black;display:none;"id="zaehlerNr"></h3>
            <h3 style="color:black;"id="adresse"></h3>
            <h3 style="color:black;display:none;"id="erfassStrasse"></h3>
            <h3 style="color:black;display:none;"id="erfassHausnr"></h3>
            <h3 style="color:black;display:none;"id="zpunktID"></h3>
            <h3 style="color:black;display:none;"id="zaehlerID"></h3>
            <h3 style="color:black;display:none;" id="ablEin"></h3>
            <h3 style="color:black;display:none;" id="gerNR"></h3>
            <h3 style="color:black;display:none;" id="AbleserNR"></h3>
            <h3 style="color:black;"id="standMin" ></h3>
            <h3 style="color:black;"id="standMax" ></h3>
            <h3 style="color:black;display:none;" id="plasib"></h3>
            <h3 style="color:black;display:none;" id="rebuild"></h3>
            <select id="alleOrte" style="color:black;width: 45%;"></select>
            <select id="alleAbleser" style="color:black;width: 45%; margin-left:20px;"></select>
            <h3 style="color:black;margin-bottom: 0;">Zustandsmeldung</h3>
            <select id="alleFehler" style="color:black;"></select>
            <h3 style="color:black;margin-bottom: 0;">Aktueller Zählerstand</h3>
            <input id="stand" type="stand" style="margin-left: 10px;"/>
            <button data-click="reset" onclick="erfassenZae();" data-role="button" style="width: 40%; margin: 1em; padding-top: 0.75em;padding-right: 1.5em;padding-bottom: 0.8125em;padding-left: 1.5em; text-align: center;">
                Erfassen
            </button>
                </div>
            <br><br><br><br><br><br>
            <div class="result-area ch50">
                <div class="results">
                    <img style="display:none;margin:5px auto; width:120px; height:120px;" id="smallImage"/>
                </div>
                <div class="separator"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="settings" style="display:none;" >
            <div id="adminMS" style="color:black;display:none;">Kennwort
            <input id="adminPass" style="text-align:right;width: 150px;color: black;"/>
            </div>
            <div id="server" style="color:black;">
                <p>Sie müssen beim ersten Start einen Server einrichten. Bitte machen Sie dies jetzt!</p>
                <p id="infofield"></p>
                <p id="os"></p>
                <p id="version">2.0.0.6</p>
                <div style="display:inline">
                    <p>Serveradresse:</p>
                    <input type="text" id="eingabe" style="width: 80%; margin-left: 5px;"/><br>
                    <button onclick="serverSpeichern();" id="serverTres"  data-role="button"  style="width: 40%; margin: 1em; padding-top: 0.75em;padding-right: 1.5em;padding-bottom: 0.8125em;padding-left: 1.5em; text-align: center;">Speichern</button>
                </div>
                <p>Qualitätsstufe (in Prozent) <input type="text" id="qalID" style="width: 100px; margin-left: 5px;"/><br></p>
                <button id="settingsCloseButton" onclick="closet();logint();qalSpeichern();" data-role="button"  style="width: 40%; margin: 1em; padding-top: 0.75em;padding-right: 1.5em;padding-bottom: 0.8125em;padding-left: 1.5em; text-align: center;">Ok</button>
            </div>
            <button id="adminButton" onclick="showServer();"  data-role="button"  style="display:none;width: 40%; margin: 1em; padding-top: 0.75em;padding-right: 1.5em;padding-bottom: 0.8125em;padding-left: 1.5em; text-align: center;">Anmelden</button> 
        </div>

        <form data-bind="events: { keyup: checkEnter }" id="logForm" style="background-color: white; padding-top: 1px;margin-left: 10px;margin-right: 10px;height:95%;box-shadow: 3px 3px black;">
            <h3 data-bind="invisible: isLoggedIn" style="color:black;font-size:16pt;">Benutzeranmeldung</h3>
            <ul data-role="listview" data-style="inset">
                <li>
                    <div style="color:black;margin-left:5px;">Geräte gesamt:
                        <div style="width: 30%;border: 1px solid gray;height: 20px;display: inline-block;float: right;border-radius: 5px;background-color: white;"></div>
                    </div>
                    <label>  
                    </label>
                </li>
                <li style="top:0;margin-left:5px;">
                    <div style="color:black;">Geräte abgelesen:
                        <div style="width: 30%;border: 1px solid gray;height: 20px;display: inline-block;float: right;border-radius: 5px;background-color: white;"></div>
                    </div>
                    <label>
                    </label>
                </li>
                <li><div style="color:black;margin-left:5px;height: 40px;">Ableser</div>
                    <label>
                        <select style="width: 30%;border: 1px solid gray;display: inline-block;float: right;border-radius: 5px;background-color: white;color:black;margin-right: 10px;" onchange="onchangeLogin();" id="Model" type="number" data-bind="value: username"> </select>
                    </label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div style="color:black;margin-left:5px;margin-top: 5px;">Kennwort</div>
                    <label>
                        <input id="passInput" onkeyup="disableButton();" onclick="cleart();" style="text-align:right;width: 30%;border: 1px solid gray;height: 20px;display: inline-block;float: right;border-radius: 5px;background-color: white;color:black;margin-right: 10px;" type="password" data-bind="value: password"/>
                    </label>
                </li><br>
                <li><button id="login" type="submit" data-role="button" data-bind="click: onLogin" value="Login" class="login-button" style="-webkit-border-radius: 5px;background-color: rgba(200,200,200,1.0);box-shadow: 3px 3px black;color:black;float:right;width:30%;">weiter</button></li>
            </ul>
            <!--<button onclick="settings();serverAnzeigen();" data-role="button"  style="width: 40%; margin: 1em; padding-top: 0.75em;padding-right: 1.5em;padding-bottom: 0.8125em;padding-left: 1.5em; text-align: center;">Einstellungen</button>
            --><br>
        </form>
    </div>
    <input onclick="openStart();" type="image" src="styles/images/zurueck.png" style="display:none;"name="image" width="40" height="40">
    <div data-role="layout" data-id="tabstrip-layout">
        <div data-role="header">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <span data-role="view-title"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" >
             <div id="footert" style="width: 100%;display:none;">
                <input id="closeButton" onclick="showHome();" type="image" src="styles/images/zurueck.png" name="image" width="40" height="40" style="bottom:0;position:fixed;">
                 <input id="closeHome" onclick="logout();" type="image" src="styles/images/zurueck.png" name="image" width="40" height="40" style="bottom:0;position:fixed;">
                <input id="uploadButton" onclick="uploadAll();" type="image" src="styles/images/uebermitteln.png" name="image" width="40" height="40" style="bottom:0;position:fixed;display:none;">
                 <!--<button id="closeButton" onclick="showHome();" data-click="reset" data-role="button" style="width: 40%; text-align: center;display:none;">Schließen</button>
                 <button id="erfassButton" data-click="reset" data-bind="click: showErfass" data-role="button" style="display:none; width: 40%; text-align: center;">Ablesen</button>
                -->
                 <input id="settingsButton" onclick="settingsH();" type="image" src="styles/images/einstellungen.png" name="image" width="40" height="40" style="bottom:0;position:fixed;display:none;">
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

No I am for exmaple scrolling down in the div named hinweiseForm and then going back using the following function:

```
function showHome(){
            document.getElementById("ablesForm").setAttribute("style","display:none;");
            document.getElementById("hinweiseForm").setAttribute("style","display:none;");
            document.getElementById("statsForm").setAttribute("style","display:none;");
            document.getElementById("home").setAttribute("style","display:block;");
            document.getElementById("erfassForm").setAttribute("style","display:none;");
            document.getElementById("uploadForm").setAttribute("style","display:none;");
            document.getElementById("terminForm").setAttribute("style","display:none;");
            document.getElementById("closeHome").setAttribute("style","display:block;");   document.getElementById("footert").setAttribute("style","position:fixed;bottom:0px;width: 100%;display:block;");
            document.getElementById("plasib").innerHTML="";
            document.getElementById("closeButton").setAttribute("style","display:none;bottom:0;postion:fixed;");
            document.getElementById("uploadButton").setAttribute("style","display:none;");
            document.getElementById("settingsButton").setAttribute("style","display:block;bottom:0;margin-left:50px;position:fixed;");
            document.getElementById("settings").setAttribute("style","display:none");
            //$("#home").data("kendoMobileScroller").reset();
            //new kendo.mobile.Application();
            //app.application = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body, { layout: "tabstrip-layout" });
        }
```

I already tried some things like the reset function but either I am not using it right or I need to do it another way. It would be really awesome if you can help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried with resetting the scroller on every page show?

Comment: Yes I tried it. I am now trying to seperate everything in its own div

Answer (score 1):

I use the scrollTo method to scroll to the top of my views.

```
app.application = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body, { 
    layout: "tabstrip-layout" 
});

// get the view scroller
var scroller = app.application.view().scroller;

/*
 * scroller.scrollTop = The number of pixels that are hidden from view above the 
 * scrollable area.
 */
if (scroller.scrollTop) {
    scroller.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```